# Python imaging library in working

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've installed PIL. But my django app failed to use it.

django log:

```
IOError at /catalogue/books/fiction/
decoder jpeg not available
```

Then i've checked the pip log about PIL installation. It reads

```
version       1.1.7
platform      linux2 2.7.3 (default, Mar 25 2013, 18:28:40)
              [GCC 4.6.3]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available
*** JPEG support not available
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
```

But i do have libjpeg-dev.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your distro the libs may not be installed in the standard location where PIL expects to find them - ie on my ubuntu 64 system libjpeg is in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. You can either edit PIL's setup.py to provide the correct path or just symlink wherever/your/libjpeg is to `/usr/lib`, then reinstall PIL.